# select element in jQuery noConflict()

Tags: jquery

This line in jQuery working with `$`.

```
$fname=$(":file:nth-of-type(" + $i + ")").val();//this is working in jquery
```

but when I convert in to **noConflict** mode the following line doesn't work:

```
 $fname=jQuery(":file:nth-of-type(" + $i + ")").val();//this is not working
```

My code is :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(document).on("change", "#iefile456", function () {
        $nod=jQuery("#item1");
        $i =1;
        while($nod.html() != "" ){
            $nod=$nod.next();
                $i=$i+1;
            }
            alert($i);
        $fname=jQuery(":file:nth-of-type(" + $i + ")").val();
        alert($fname);
    });
});
```

`alert($i)` was working but `alert($fname)` was not working.

Comment: Is this inside of another function? If you could post more code (before/after) that would help greatly.

Comment: "It does not work." Perfectly describes the problem, really. Errors? What does $fname contain?

Comment: It sounds like `$fname` and `$i` may still be defined using `$` instead of `jQuery`, which means `jQuery(...)` can't use them properly. Also, you don't need to use `$` before your variable names.

Comment: Where are you calling `.noConflict()`?

Comment: i am writing a module for joomla.I called .noConflict in php tag and .noconflict was working good because i test it.